# What is wrong with the syntax of my setup to connect to mongoDB Atlas clusters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbPath = "mongodb+srv://<Admin>:<615d5846c>@cluster0-4gelt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

var app = express();

mongoose.connect(dbPath,
  { useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
  })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB success!'))
  .catch(() => console.log('MongoDB fail!'));
```

So i want connect my app to my mongoDB atlas cluster, but i dont know why, the connection fail.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you check the prerequisites before connecting to the Mongo DB cluster:

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/

and then you can check this out: 
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the angle brackets in the connection string :

```
var dbPath = "mongodb+srv://Admin:615d5846c@cluster0-4gelt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Those are just for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect :

```
var dbPath = "mongodb+srv://<Admin>:<615d5846c>@cluster0-4gelt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Correct :

```
var dbPath = "mongodb+srv://Admin:615d5846c@cluster0-4gelt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

The chevrons should not be present in the path.